# Domain for $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity definition

Tags: metric-spaces

Does epsilon-delta continuity implicitly requires that there would be at least one non-trivial Cauchy sequence converging in the function's domain?

Generally the criteria is introduced with no restrictions of the metric spaces.

I am confused that If I am allowed to use a trivial Cauchy sequence I can prove continuity of any function on ANY domain where this function is defined (re the comment below) - not only on a discrete domain where the trivial is the only one converging to a point, but literally on any domain as a trivial Cauchy sequence would converge to a point in the domain on any domain and similarity a trivial Cauchy sequence for the range would converge to the function's value at this point.

Therefore the epsilon-delta should require at least one non-trivial Cauchy sequence in the domain or I am terribly wrong in my logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  The function $f:\{0\} \to \{0\}$ given by $f(0) = 0$ is $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuous, but there is no non-trivial convergent sequence.

However, note that without a non-trivial convergent sequence converging to $x = c$, the limit $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$ is not defined.  So, our above $f$ is continuous, but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

It would seem then that the naive definition of continuity "$f$ is continuous at $c$ if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = f(c)$" is not *quite* correct.

Comment: ...If we have not $x_n\neq x$ in our definition.

Comment: Indeed, any function on this domain is continuous.  This is similarly true for any domain consisting only of isolated points: any function from such a domain is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of continuity.

> I am confused that If I am allowed to use a trivial Cauchy sequence I can prove continuity of any function on ANY domain where this function is defined (re the comment below) - not only on a discrete domain where the trivial is the only one converging to a point, but literally on any domain as a trivial Cauchy sequence would converge to a point in the domain on any domain and similarity a trivial Cauchy sequence for the range would converge to the function's value at this point.

True, the trivial sequence satisfies the definition. But the property holding for any sequence doesn't mean it holds for one choice you make. It means the property holds for **all Cauchy sequences**. This means you have to check that the property holds for the trivial sequence **and** that it also holds for any other Cauchy sequence.

If the domain is not discrete, there are Cauchy sequences which are not trivial. This means you have to check the definition for these sequences too, not only for the trivial sequence. Checking just for the trivial sequence is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy sequences are not used in the definition of continuity. Suppose $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ are metric spaces; if $a\in X$ and $r>0$, $B_X(a;r)$ will mean
$$
B_X(a;r)=\{a\in X: d_X(a,x)<r\}.
$$

**Definition.** A map $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous at $a$ if, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
x\in B_X(a;\delta) \text{ implies } f(x)\in B_Y(f(a);\varepsilon).
$$

**Theorem.** A map $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous at $a$ if, for all sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$,
$$
\text{if } x_n\to a \text{, then } f(x_n)\to f(a).
$$

I write $x_n\to a$ to mean that the sequence converges to $a$, that is, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n$ such that, for $m>n$, $x_n\in B_X(a;\varepsilon)$.

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $x_n\to a$; fix $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $\delta$ as in the definition above. Then, there exists $n$ such that, for $n>m$, $x_n\in B_X(a;\delta)$. But this implies that, for $m>n$, $f(x_n)\in B_Y(f(a);\varepsilon)$, which is what was to be proved.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $f$ is *not* continuous at $a$. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that, given any $\delta>0$, we can find $x\in B_X(a;\delta)$ with $f(x)\notin B_Y(f(a);\varepsilon)$. In particular, given any positive integer $n$, there is $x_n\in B_X(a;1/n)$ such that $f(x_n)\notin B_Y(f(a);\varepsilon)$.

Now, the sequence $(x_n)$ is easily seen to converge to $a$, but it's also easy to see that $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to $f(a)$. QED

It is true that every convergent sequence is Cauchy, but this is irrelevant in the proof and in the statement of the theorem. Moreover, a constant sequence *is* Cauchy and these constant sequences (or, better, *eventually constant* sequences) are unavoidable in this context.

To make a simple example, suppose the metric on $X$ is *discrete*, that is
$$
d_X(a,b)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $a=b$},\\
1 & \text{if $a\ne b$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then *any* map $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous at all points of $X$, but no sequence in $X$ is Cauchy unless it is eventually constant.

Cauchy sequences enter in the context of *completeness* of metric spaces, where the Cauchy convergence test ensures a sequence is convergent. In the context of continuity we are always dealing with sequences we *know* are convergent or we know where they should converge to.

Among the sequences needed to state the theorem the eventually constant sequence are certainly considered, but you have to consider ***all*** sequences converging to $a$.